# $f(x) = O(x^{-1})$ as $x \to \infty$ implies that $f(x) = o(x^{-1+\delta})$ for any $\delta > 0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f(x) = O(x^{-1})$ as $x \to \infty$. What can we say about $f(x)$ in terms of small o? I know we can say $f(x) = o(1)$ or $f(x) = o(x^{-1/2})$ for example. It seems in fact that we could say $f(x) = o(x^{-1+\delta})$ for any $\delta > 0$. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes I agree. Why don't you write out a proof?

Comment: Well my main issue is that it seems the notation '$f(x) = o(x^{-1+\delta})$ for any $\delta > 0$' is a bit ugly. Usually we use the big O and little o notation because, among other things, it makes things less ugly. So I'm wondering if there is nicer notation for converting from big O to little o?